# Efficient SASS for loops

Tags: sass

I currently have some hand-coded SASS like this;

```
.tl1 td, .tl1 /deep/ th,
.tl2 td, .tl2 /deep/ th,
.tl3 td, .tl3 /deep/ th,
.tl4 td, .tl4 /deep/ th,
.tl5 td, .tl5 /deep/ th,
....
{ text-align: left; }
```

I'm trying to refactor this into a SASS for loop, however, It's not clear how to do this without making a new declaration for each line.

IE - this SASS loop;

```
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  .tl#{$i}  td,  .tl#{$i}  /deep/ th {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

makes each statement atomic, like this;

```
.tl1 td, .tl1 th 
{
  text-align: left;
}
.tl2 td, .tl2 th 
{
  text-align: left;
}
.tl3 td, .tl3 th 
{
  text-align: left;
}
...
```

**Is there a way to group all the selectors together, as in the hand coded example?**

Comment: Any CSS minifier will group these selectors for you, so in production style there will be no duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@extend` inside your loop to group different rules with same values.

```
%text-left{
  text-align: left;
}

@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  .tl#{$i}{
    td, th, /* deep */ th {
      @extend %text-left;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly!
I've read about @extend now and this makes sense - thankyou for teaching me something new! :)

Comment: `@extend` is powerful! @McStrudel Thanks!